# why not reuse message buffer in case of tcp

Tags: c, tcp

I have seen that many open source frameworks and best practices for tcp/ip suggest to never reuse a buffer that you have handed to tcp layer for transport. What is the reason behind it? Is it not true that buffer simply gets copied into kernel, so what is the parnaoia about not reusing the buffer?
A typical example would of the above would be

```
char data[1024] = {'1', '2'.................'1024'};
write(socket, data, 1024);
data = {'a', 'b','c'...........};  //reusing the buffer
```

ZeroMQ provides api to create a buffer and delete it and they strong suggest to not use it. Netperf creates a ringbuffer and makes sure that it never reuses the buffer that it current wrote to the socket.

Comment: Could you be more specific, and copy-paste a fragment where it is done, along with a suggested alternative? My only guess at the moment is that this may be done in anticipation of [zero-copy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-copy) APIs.

Comment: It's got to depend exactly on the interface you're using.  If the code you wrote above is busted, then a LOT of programs are busted.  The only reason to hang on to the buffer after you've called write() is if write can't write all the data, and you have to call it again.

Comment: I have never seen this pointless recommendation in over 20 years of network programming. Where did you read it?

Answer (score 2):

`write()` and `send()` will both copy your data to the TCP "send window" so you don't have to worry about changing it within your program after those calls.  Note, however, that non-blocking sockets may not copy *all* your data and so you should check the return code to find out how many bytes were actually written.

It's possible that some custom TCP stacks, perhaps for very small embedded systems, required the data to stay around but no mainstream OS would require such.